# How to get multiple lines from HoughLinesP(openCV) on Android?

Tags: android, opencv, kotlin, hough-transform

I'd like to get multiple lines from this process.

```
override fun onCameraFrame(inputFrame: CvCameraViewFrame): Mat? {
    mRgba = inputFrame.rgba()

    // generate gray scale and blur
    Imgproc.cvtColor(mRgba, mRgbaFiltered, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    Imgproc.blur(mRgbaFiltered, mRgbaFiltered, Size(3.0, 3.0))

    // detect the edges
    val mMat = Mat()
    val ratio = 4

    // Find Canny Edges
    Imgproc.Canny(mRgbaFiltered, mMat, threshold, threshold * ratio.toDouble())

    // Find horizontal lines
    val lines = Mat()
    Imgproc.HoughLinesP(mMat, lines, 1.0, Math.PI / 180, 80, 100.0, 10.0)

    // Change Color to RGB
    Imgproc.cvtColor(mMat, mMat, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

    // draw lines
    for (i in 0 until lines.cols()) {
        val `val` = lines[0, i]
        Imgproc.line(
            mMat,
            Point(`val`[0], `val`[1]),
            Point(`val`[2], `val`[3]),
            Scalar(0.0, 255.0, 0.0),
            1
        )
    }

    num_lines = lines.cols()
    updateHandler.postDelayed(updateRunnable, 500)

    return mMat
}
```

However, I only get one line as you can see below. I need to draw all the lines.. And How can I do that?

[image]

Comment: Can you share the pure image instead of result?

Comment: It's just a stack of cards. @Yunus

Comment: I tried it with these parameters ```Canny(img, dst, 80, 240, 3)``` and ```HoughLinesP(dst, lines, 1.0, CV_PI/180, 50, 100.0, 10.0 )```. And its able to find all the lines. I think its about the parameters you used. Can you share threshold value in your code to test yours?

Comment: What's the third param in Canny? mine was Canny(img, dst, 80, 320), HoughLinesP(dst, lines, 1.0, CV_PI/180, 80, 100.0, 10.0 ) @YunusTemurlenk

Comment: ```Canny(input,output,threshold1,threshold2,apertureSize)``` When I used yours,I still get all the lines. I couldnt find out the difference

Comment: Its probably about drawing lines, I am not familiar with this language so just be sure you are drawing for all lines.

Comment: Could you share it in your language then?

Answer (score 0):

I just changed the houghline and canny parameters.

Here is my code:

```
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    Mat img = imread("/ur/image/directory/lines.png");

    imshow("Source",img);

    Mat dst, cdst;
    Canny(img, dst, 80, 250);
    cvtColor(dst, cdst, CV_GRAY2BGR);

    vector<Vec4i> lines;
    HoughLinesP(dst, lines, 1.0, CV_PI/180, 80, 100.0, 10.0 );
    for( size_t i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++ )
    {
        Vec4i l = lines[i];
        line( cdst, Point(l[0], l[1]), Point(l[2], l[3]), Scalar(0,0,255), 3, CV_AA);
    }
    imshow("Output", cdst);

    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Um.. It doesn't work.. I guess the for loop is incorrect.

Comment: I think also like that

Comment: Well, I think it's not the loop problem. I tested HoughLinesP() out and it always gets only one line. I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change it to..

cols -> rows

lines[0, i] -> lines[i, 0]

```
// draw lines
for (i in 0 until lines.rows()) {
    val dArr = lines[i, 0]
    Imgproc.line(
        mMat,
        Point(dArr[0], dArr[1]),
        Point(dArr[2], dArr[3]),
        Scalar(0.0, 255.0, 0.0),
        1
    )
}
```